# Trying to search on an API with an input value without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my code take the input value when I click the search button and use that value to search in the gifphy API without refreshing the page. I am currently getting a type error:

> `TypeError`: `undefined` is not an object (evaluating `subjectData.data.images.original`).

Any help would be appreciated

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', getGif)
async function getGif() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/translate?api_key=MYKEY&s=${inputValue}`, {
      mode: 'cors'
    });
    const subjectData = await response.json();
    img.src = subjectData.data.images.original.url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
getGif();
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="search" id='input'>
<button id='button'>Search</button>
<img src="#" />
```

data: [] (0)

meta: {status: 200, msg: "OK", response_id: "095528aed75dc51ed9ac4439ceac93400de8f48c"}

Comment: can you provide a sample result of json call?

Comment: You have to debug it yourself! If we tell you what is wrong you would not get the lesson from it. Open devtools and place a breakpoint after the line with `subjectData =`

Comment: you are not handling case if response status is not 200

Comment: updated the post for mohammad. The status is 200.

Comment: what is happening is that your request is not returning any results hence you're trying to load an image based on an object that doesn't exist. Just put an if conditional to check if length is greater than 0, then attach your object value to the image src

Comment: @gugateider so if I put my img.src in a if conditional for subjectData.length > 0?

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have gotten it to work on my end. I swapped your async/awaits out for just fetch, but it works fine. Let me know if you're able to work with this or migrate it into your existing setup. If you want, I can try to reformat it back into your async/awasit setup.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', getGif);
const apiKey = document.getElementById('apikey').value;
const searchField = document.getElementById('input');
function getGif() {
  return fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/translate?api_key=${apiKey}&s=${searchField.value}`, { mode: 'cors' }).then((response) => response.json()).then(data => img.src = (data.data?.images?.original?.url || "#"));
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
img[src="#"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="API Key" id="apikey">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search…" id="input">
<button id='button'>Search</button>
<img src="#" />
```